# Can recursive relationships be binary?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

It is said that recursive relationships are unary. But, is there any binary recursive relationship?

Answer (score 0):

In some approaches, people count the number of distinct entity sets involved in a relationship. In this view, recursive relationships on a single entity set (e.g. parent/child) are called unary, and relationships on two distinct entity sets are called binary. However, to establish a cyclic dependency between two entity sets, we would need two distinct relationships, each with a different entity set as determinant. If you're looking for a recursive single binary relationship from this point of view, the answer is no.

However, this approach of counting distinct entity sets breaks down when trying to distinguish between relationships that involve 2, 3 or more entities at a time from the same set. It also can't effectively describe relationships with multiple roles in which more than one, but not all, involve the same entity set.

A better approach is to classify relationships by the number of roles. In this view, a recursive relationship between one entity set in two roles (e.g. parent/child) is called a binary relationship, and there are no non-trivial recursive unary relationships.

While the latter approach is more sound, there's still some ambiguity that derives from the entity-relationship model itself, e.g. how to classify relationships involving associative entities (i.e. relationships on relationships).